# refresh datagridview after cellformatting event

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, fonts, runtime, cell-formatting

I'm programming in Visual Basic Net and I fill a Datagridview with a MySql table manually. I want to change font, style of a row if meet some conditions.

The Datagridview.CellFormatting event can do that, but after leave the event my datagridview don't refresh. Below the code:

```
Private Sub gridUsers_CellFormatting(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles gridUsers.CellFormatting
    With DirectCast(sender, DataGridView)
        If .CurrentRow.Cells("eliminado").Value Is "Si" Then
            .CurrentRow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.DarkRed
            .CurrentRow.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.White
        ElseIf .CurrentRow.Cells("condicion").Value Is "No" Then
            .CurrentRow.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.DarkRed
            .CurrentRow.DefaultCellStyle.Font = New Font("Verdana", 8, FontStyle.Strikeout Or FontStyle.Bold)
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

I don't know why, but whenever I click any row in the grid, or scroll down and up, the lines' colors change. How to refresh the style of the cells in the datagridview

Thanks for your help...

Comment: Dont create a font each time for each cell.  Create a YesFont and a NoFont in form load and use the same one over and over.  You might want to do all that in the RowPrePaint event

Comment: thanks Plutonix, I made a solution... You can change fonts in cells in RowsAdded event, so I have another question; how to paint the cells in the same RowsAdded event?